# How can I see another user's "likes" on Pandora?

Tags: pandora

I want to see my friend's liked songs on Pandora.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know their username and plug it into the URL

```
http://www.pandora.com/profile/likes/{username}
```

Here are my likes:

http://www.pandora.com/profile/likes/mickeyslater8